# How to generate signal who have value less then one clk in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

How to generate signal who have value less then one clk in vhdl?

Signal req is generate base on input signal dat1 and dat2. If they are equals, signal req have value of 1 less then one clk.

[image]

On diagram down is shown how signal need to looks.

[image]

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: In simulation, or in synthesis? You can't do this in synthesis without another clock from somewhere.

Comment: Saying "less than one clk" is not good enough. You must specify the **minimum** and **maximum** allowable widths of this pulse in seconds.

Comment: Its for synthesis. :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to use the high period from the clock to 'gate' a compare signal. But you might still end up with some 'runt' pulses. This is what might get:
[image]

This is where the 'runt' pulses can come from:

At the beginning your individual `dat1` bits will have tiny delays to get to the final value. Thus your compare might not straight go to 1 or 0 but take a while to settle. Your clock gate might filter some of those out, or not. Also they may be so short/fast that the following logic (especially of it is a slow output port) filters them out. But if the `req` is uses as some sort of gate/clock you should be aware that they might happen.

A bigger problem is at the end. Your `dat1` will change *after* the clock edge so between it changing, it is very possible that the `req` signal comes out again. Here you have the issue that your individual dat1 bits will have tiny delays to get to the final value and thus again you can have runt pulses after your runt pulse.

Comment: Thank you for idea. Do you know how to write this in vhdl?

Comment: I could probably work it out. (I am writing Verilog 99% of the time). But Stack Exchange is not a code writing service. Try it yourself and if you get stuck post a new question.